# Floating point exception (core dumped) #694457

Tags: c++

I don't know C++ well, and I don't understand why but this error occurred:
 Floating point exception (core dumped)

I don't know how can I fix it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a = 251;
    int b = 0;

    while (a > 0) {
        a = a / 10;
        b++;
    }
    int c = 2;
    int d = 1;
    while (c <= b) {
        d = d * 10;
        c++;
    }
    cout << d;
    int answer = 0;
    int f = d;
    int g = 1;
    float help;
    while (b > 0) {
        help = (a / (d * g)) *(d / f);
        answer = answer + (int)help;
        a = a % (d * g);
        g = g * (1 / 10);
        f = f * (1 / 10);
        b--;
    }

    cout << answer;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Guessing that `g` or `f` goes to 0, which makes you divide by zero.

Comment: Probably, `help` overflows with small enough values of `f`. Step through with a debugger to find out.

Comment: [Stop it!!!](https://pogoprinciple.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/divide3.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Counter-intuitively, a "floating-point exception" is an exception kicked out by your CPU and/or Operating System when you attempt to perform *integer division by zero*.

C++ makes this operation undefined; your computer outright prohibits it.

Check all your variables when you step through your program with your debugger, and remember that `1 / 10` is zero, not 0.1, because it's integer division. (This mistake propagates to the next iteration of your loop, where you attempt to use this zero value as a divisor.)

Dividing a floating-point number by zero is more well-defined and ISTR it will kick out the special value *inf*.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have "core dumped" you can use GDB to investigate your crash: `gdb binary core`. Here is what happens in your code:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
#0  (...)
    at (...):LINE_NUM
LINE_NUM             help = (a /(d * g)) *(d /f);
```

During second iteration your `f` and `g` are already equal to 0. In Linux you can catch `SIGFPE` signal and handle the error, or you can check the variables in your code before performing a division.

Answer (score 0):

[As answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52890336/10528284)

Better use:

```
g = g/10;
f = f/10;
```

for integral values.
Also check for **g** and **f** not  equal to zero before dividing.

I hope this helps ;)